# Hyper V AVHDX will not boot after host os reinstall

Tags: hyper-v

I had some issues with the host OS, therefore I have reinstalled it. Hyper V was hosting a machine with a Windows 10 on it.

After the server reinstall the AVHDX (I have a checkpoint which works but it is too old to run it from there) can no longer be booted.

The error is

> Failed to power on with error The device is not ready

[image]

I tried both importing the machine and creating a new one using the AVHDX as boot drive but both fail the same way.

I tried to merge the images but when opening it I get some other error.

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Wizards.EditVhd.ActionPage.SetPageLayout(VirtualHardDiskSettingData selectedDisk, VirtualHardDiskState selectedDiskState, Boolean reconnect)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Wizards.EditVhd.NamePage.FailureRetrievingSelectedVirtualDisk(VirtualHardDiskSettingData diskSettingData, VirtualHardDiskState diskState, Exception exception)
```

I tried to hit continue, I get a loading cursor but it stays like that for hours and it is not doing anything.

Comment: I had some issues with the host OS  .... I have reinstalled it. .... Did you run all updates including optional updates. Sometimes .NET hides in optional updates amongst other updates.

Comment: You think it might be related to the .net libraries? I installed all the updates, yet the OS has .net framework 4.7. Should I try installing 3.5 as well?

Comment: I don't think Hyper-V needs .NET 3.5.  I am not sure why Hyper-V does not work after a new install of Windows. I will look around a bit.

Comment: Tried installing the 3.5 which includes 2.0 and 3.0 as well and the issue persists.

Comment: You need to enable Hyper-V in Programs and Features, Windows Features after the reinstall. Did you do that? Also restart the host after enabling Hyper-V

Comment: Did that, yes. The machine will boot from the VHDX but not from the AVHDX.

Comment: Pretty sure you corrupted Hyper-V's internal data structures somehow. Your VM is probably incomplete. You could be missing disk files, suspended state files, differencing images, …

Comment: Also, this error is not related to .NET updates or anything like that at all. The wizard is crashing because data structures are corrupted. Something that is supposed to be there is not.

Comment: Is there any way to recover what is not there? The machines were placed in a completely different HDD than the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the following steps:

1. Moved both AVHDX and VHDX images to Win Server 2016
2. Opened AVHDX with Edit Disk and relinked it from the Hyper V manager
3. Created a new instance with the VHDX as main drive (since AVHDX cannot be added at this step) !!! important: do not start it !!!
4. Edit the machine drive and replace the VHDX with the AVHDX
5. Boot the machine - no errors or warnings at this point

Conclusions:

1. Reinstalling Win 2019 Srv with the same settings might break things up
2. The image editor of Win 2019 Srv has some issue given the errors presented at first (not related to the image itself)